# Check if a row was inserted into table during insert - postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a condition to insert a row, only if that "file" wasn't inserted into a "person", if a person already have a "file", the file should go to other "person":

```
WITH get_files AS (
    SELECT
        type,
        country
    FROM files
    WHERE title IS NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO history_person_file (
    name,
    document_type,
    age
)
SELECT
    p.name,
    f.type,
    p.age
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN get_files f
ON p.country = f.country
ON conflict (name) do nothing;
```

For example, i have 2 files with country "France",

I need that person 1 have a file "Type 1" and person 2 have a file "Type 2"

In other words, just 1 file per person, else the file should go to other person.

I guess that "ON conflict (name, country)..." would help me, but country isn't a constraint